# PHP Call to a member function saveXML() on a non-object on AJAX POST?

Tags: php, xml, jquery

Can anyone see what's wrong with my code? The error I'm getting is as follows:

Fatal error: Call to a member function saveXML() on a non-object in /path/to/php/file.php on line 35

Basically I'm just trying to update an XML nodeValue which changes the UI depending on the value set in the "AVAILABILITY" tag.

==================== UPDATE ====================

The XML file is now not being overwritten with the new value for the ('STATUS') node inside ('AVAILABILITY') tag, is there something I'm doing wrong?!

================================================

XML Structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WORK>
    <AVAILABILITY>
        <STATUS>0</STATUS> // Not being changed?!
    </AVAILABILITY>
    <SLIDE>
        <ID>YY001</ID>
        <TITLE>YourEdentity</TITLE>
        <LINK>http://youredentity.campearce.co.uk</LINK>
        <THUMB>your_ed.png</THUMB>
        <CAPTION>This is YourEdentity</CAPTION>
    </SLIDE>
</WORK>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php

$url = "../content/slides.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

if(!file_exists($url))
{
echo "Unable to locate file";
}
else
{
$root = $xml->WORK;
$slides = $root->SLIDE;

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action']))
{
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action)
    {
        case 'deleteslide' : delete_slide(); break;
        case 'createslide' : create_slide(); break;
        case 'changeavail' : change_avail($root, $_POST['status'], $xml, $url); break;
    }   
}
}

function change_avail($root_node, $status, $xml, $location){

$availability_node = $root_node->AVAILABILITY;
$status_node[0] = $availability_node->STATUS;
parse_str($status, $statustr);
$status_node[0] = $statustr;

file_put_contents($location, $xml->asXML());

echo $xml->asXML();
}

function save_toxml($xml, $location)
{
$fp = fopen($location, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $xml->asXML());
fclose($fp);
echo $xml->asXML();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function change_avail you didnt have variable $xml. Transmit this var:

```
function change_avail($root_node, $status, DOMDocument $xml)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! But now the changes aren't actually being saved? The XML is the same, is there something I'm doing wrong in the code to change the STATUS node inside AVAILABILITY?

Comment: My english not so good as I want it. If you want to change STATUS, do this:

`$xml->AVAILABILITY[0]->STATUS = $newStatus`
`$xml->asXML('path/new/saved/file.xml')`